# Violation of Primary Key constraint error

Tags: sql-server-2008, primary-key, duplicates

I am using SSMS 2008 and trying to insert with this query but am getting the following error:

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_j5c_MasterMeasures'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.j5c_MasterMeasures'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Here is my query:

```
insert into J5C_MasterMeasures (studentid, measuredate, measureid, RIT)

select A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename+' ' +B.LabelName, A.score_14
from [J5C_Measures_Sys] A
join [J5C_ListBoxMeasures_Sys] B on A.MeasureID = B.MeasureID 
join sysobjects so on so.name = 'J5C_Measures_Sys' 
join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id 
join [J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys] v on v.Score_field_id = sc.name
where so.type = 'u' and sc.name = 'score_14' and a.score_14 is not null 
AND A.STUDENTID IS NOT NULL AND A.MEASUREDATE IS NOT NULL AND B.MEASURENAME IS NOT NULL
group by a.studentid, a.measuredate, B.measurename, B.LabelName, A.score_14
--HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The strange thing is that if I run just the SELECT query (without the INSERT) and include the HAVING COUNT statement, it returns 0 records for > 1.  So I don't know where the duplicate is coming from!

Comment: Does J5C_MasterMeasures already have any data in it? It is possible that the duplicate is caused by data already present in that table that is being added again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your earlier question, i believe that your primary key is A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename. Please correct me if i am wrong on this.

Since you are grouping by two additional columns  B.LabelName and A.score_14 in addition to your columns of your composite primary key, if there are any duplicates - which there can be provided they have different values of either  B.LabelName or A.score_14 - you will violate your primary key constraint and this error will be thrown.

Your data will just not be unique enough to satisfy your primary key - which states that ONLY ONE ROW with a unique combination of A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename can exist in your table

Answer (score 0):

Is there data already in the J5C_MasterMeasures table? If so make sure that what you are inserting doesn't already exist

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename+' ' +B.LabelName, A.score_14
  from [J5C_Measures_Sys] A
  join [J5C_ListBoxMeasures_Sys] B on A.MeasureID = B.MeasureID 
  join sysobjects so on so.name = 'J5C_Measures_Sys' 
  join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id 
  join [J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys] v on v.Score_field_id = sc.name
 where so.type = 'u' and sc.name = 'score_14' and a.score_14 is not null 
   AND A.STUDENTID IS NOT NULL AND A.MEASUREDATE IS NOT NULL AND B.MEASURENAME IS NOT NULL
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM J5C_MasterMeasures x
                   WHERE x.studentid = a.studentid
                     AND x.measuredate = a.measuredate
                     AND x.measureid = B.measurename +' '+ B.LabelName)
group by a.studentid, a.measuredate, B.measurename, B.LabelName, A.score_14
```

The `NOT EXISTS` will filter out already existing data.

Answer (score 0):

You should double-check your HAVING test.  Make sure you are only including the column(s) that comprises the PK in your GROUP BY clause.